# DMS task getting failed on Oracle on-going replication (Full load works fine)

Tags: database-migration, aws-dms, dms

We're using AWS DMS to migrate oracle databases into s3 buckets and after successfully running the full load on Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 hosted in rds, the on-going replication is failing with error:
Failed to add the REDO sequence xxxx; to LogMiner in thread 1;. Replication task could not find the required REDO log on the source database to read changes from. Please check redo log retention settings and retry

- I already checked that the archivelog retention hours was set to 24

Have anyone came across the same issue!? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to fix the issue after rerunning the grants script as documented in aws dms. We could not find the root cause but some privilege was not assigned at first and impacted the redologs access https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.Oracle.html#CHAP_Source.Oracle.Amazon-Managed